# How to have sound drivers and settings the same as they were before from a fresh install?

Tags: 11.04, sound

I have esound now ...and I had a problem with my audio jacks with pulse audio...so I removed it and now I have esound.....now I want it back as original as it was before like from a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.04... any fixes? (I have TeamViewer so if you want to help me add me on facebook: Kevin Maghuyop)

Comment: Uhm, why would you want it back to where it was? I.E. broken and non-functional...

Comment: If I could I would set a bounty here too. +1

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to install pulseaudio from the software center or synaptic package manger and disable/uninstall esound via the same method...